# how do i get data from azure queue message (service bus)

Tags: azure

I need to get data from service bus from my console application, instead of my data I've got System.UnauthorizedAccessException error 401
I've got 2 static readonly string that I don't know how to use
You may require one or both of the services below depending on the level of detail that you need-

```
    //sample usage string briefingDetailsByIdURI = string.Format(Constants.BRIEFING_DETAILS_ID_URI, brfId);

    public static readonly string ID_URI = "https://trtrtrtr.servicebus.windows.net/trtrtr/trttrttr/{0}";



    //sample usage - string URI = string.Format(Constants.sdgsdgg, sgsgsg, sgsgsg);

    public static readonly string DETAIL_ID_URI = "https://trtrtrtr.servicebus.windows.net/trtrtr/trrtrttr/{0}/{1}";
```

I just went in app.config and put this with the right namespace and password

```
<appSettings>
<!-- Service Bus specific app setings for messaging connections -->
<add key="Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString"        value="Endpoint=sb://<namespace>.servicebus.windows.net/;
 SharedAccessKeyName=Root      stManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=<paasword> />
```

after that I went in my console program.cs

Console.Title = "Receiver2";

```
        // Creating the topic if it does not exist already using the service bus connection string stored in the app.config file
        string connectionString =
            CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString");
        //appSettings dans appsettings getSettings()

        //connection au service bus
        var namespaceManager =
            NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
        //verification  si queue existe

        if (!namespaceManager.QueueExists("CommentaireQueue"))
        {
            namespaceManager.CreateQueue("CommentaireQueue");
        }


        QueueClient client = QueueClient.Create("CommentaireQueue");
        Console.WriteLine("test console");
        //boucle infini pour recevoir tous les messages
        while (true)
        {
            var message = client.Receive();
            if (message != null)
            {
                var comm = message.GetBody<string>();
                string myString = comm.Contenu;
                try
                {


                        Console.WriteLine(myString);

                }
                finally
                {
                    //enlever le message de la queue
                    message.Complete();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to connect to the queue

```
QueueClient _client;
        var connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString");
        var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
        if (!namespaceManager.QueueExists(QueueName))
        {
            namespaceManager.CreateQueue(QueueName);
        }

        _client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, QueueName);
```

Instead of running a while loop. You could be using OnMessage() like this:

```
_client.OnMessage(message =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //do logic
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        message.Abandon();
                        throw new Exception(e.Message);
                    }
                });
```

Make sure the connections string is set correct in your Azure ServiceConfiguration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="App" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="4" osVersion="*" schemaVersion="2015-04.2.6">
  <Role name="App">
    <Instances count="1" />
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString" value="THE CONNECTION STRING" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
  </Role>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

Comment: the problem is creating the queue namespace.createQueue throws an unauthorizedException

Comment: I can see that you're using the CloudConfigurationManager too.
Make sure that the setting "Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString" is in your ServiceConfigration.Cloud (and local) of your Azure Project.

I updated my answer with the service configuration

Comment: thank  you Jeffrey, but isn't what I've done in the app.config                         <appSettings>
    <!-- Service Bus specific app setings for messaging connections -->
    <add key="Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString"  value="Endpoint=sb://lqlqlqlqlq.servicebus.windows.net//;SharedAccessKeyName=name;SharedAccessKey=key" />

  </appSettings>

Comment: it's a console application the only way I configure this in my opinion is app.config and i've done it

Comment: I understand, unfortunatly I cannot seem to find anything wrong at this moment.
Have you tried looking at following posts, the error looks simular:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032506/how-to-create-queue-in-windows-azure
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558299/servicebus-throws-401-unauthorized-error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35292136/how-do-i-re-use-a-token-service-bus and what do you think about this?